# Celery --beat on Heroku vs Worker and Clock processes

Tags: django, multithreading, heroku, celery, clock

> Blockquote

I have a periodic task that I am implementing on heroku procfile using worker:

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn voltbe2.wsgi --log-file - --log-level debug
worker: celery -A voltbe2 worker --beat --events --loglevel INFO
```

**tasks.py**

```
class PullXXXActivityTask(PeriodicTask):
    """
    A periodic task that fetch data every 1 mins.
    """
    run_every = timedelta(minutes=1)

    def run(self, **kwargs):
        abc= MyModel.objects.all()
        for rk in abc:
            rk.pull()
        logger = self.get_logger(**kwargs)
        logger.info("Running periodic task for XXX.")

        return True
```

For this periodictask, I need the --beat (I checked by turning it off, and it does not repeat the task). So, in some way, the `--beat` does the work of a clock (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes)

My concern is: if I scale the worker `heroku ps:scale worker=2` to 2x dynos, I am seeing that there are two beats running on worker.1 and worker.2 from the logs:

```
 Aug 25 09:38:11 emstaging app/worker.2: [2014-08-25 16:38:11,580: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task apps.notification.tasks.SendPushNotificationTask (apps.notification.tasks.SendPushNotificationTask)
Aug 25 09:38:20 emstaging app/worker.1: [2014-08-25 16:38:20,239: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task apps.notification.tasks.SendPushNotificationTask (apps.notification.tasks.SendPushNotificationTask)
```

The log displayed is for a different periodic task, but the key point is that both worker dynos are getting signals to do the same task from their respective clocks, while in fact there should be one clock that ticks and after every XX seconds decides what to do, and gives that task to the least loaded `worker.n` dyno

More on why a single clock is essential is here : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes#custom-clock-processes

Is this a problem and how to avoid this, if so?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should have a separate worker for the beat process.

```
web: gunicorn voltbe2.wsgi --log-file - --log-level debug
worker: celery -A voltbe2 worker -events -loglevel info 
beat: celery -A voltbe2 beat
```

Now you can scale the worker task without affecting the beat one.

Alternatively, if you won't always need the extra process, you can continue to use -B in the worker task but also have a second task - say, extra_worker - which is normally set to 0 dynos, but which you can scale up as necessary. The important thing is to always keep the task with the beat at 1 process

Comment: Thanks @Daniel . So if i understand correctly, as long as there is a "beat" that is given out by ANY of the Procfile processes, it will be propagated throughout the app and all the workers can hear this 'beat'? Is there any doc on heroku tht explains this?

Comment: It's not really anything to do with Heroku, nor is it really a beat that other workers are listening to. Rather, the 'beat' job simply puts all jobs that are due onto the queue, and then they are picked up in exactly the normal way by the worker(s).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for this answer, please can you provide a reference for futher reading on this .. I can't seem to find any on heroku docs.

Comment: I was having issue running my celery and flower commands on Procfile that is been deployed on railway. i was able to fix that with the suggestion above using your suggestion.